# SQL: Out of Memory error | Heroku Postgres + Hasura GraphQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, graphql, hasura

I am currently using Postgres hosted on Heroku and Hasura for GraphQL. When having slightly higher amount of active users (~100) we are experiencing enormous connection issues.
Looking at the heroku logs it says  "sql_error_code = 53200 DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 224 in memory context "MessageContext"."
However, the metrics show that we should have enough RAM (max used 33%) and dynos. 
Is this a problem of connections between postgres and hasura? Can it be caused by a certain expensive Query? What other configurations should I look at?

Comment: I think it is an issue about concurrent connections limit. I found a resource that describes the scenario. Please check it out. https://blog.heroku.com/connection_limit_guidance